# How can I fill the circle when pressing on F in blender 2.83?

Tags: blender

The tutorial is using blender 2.82

I added a circle and when I change it to edit mode and press on the F key instead filling the circle it's giving me this error :

This is the circle in object mode :

[image: Circle]

Then changing to edit mode and pressing F :

[image: No points were selected]

Following a tutorial when he press on F the result is :

[image: Tutorial filled circle]

I didn't see in the tutorial that he selected any points or how to do it.

Comment: I guess you better ask your question here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: use Add -> Mesh -> Circle, and always use mesh unless otherwise stated.

You added `curve -> circle` but you should add `mesh -> circle`

There are many different types of object in blender. Mesh and curve are different and has different purpose in blender:

**Mesh** is basic and most used type of geometry in blender. It's made of vertices (points) and edges (straight lines between points) and faces (at last 3 edges creating a plane).

**Curve** is made from points with handles connected with curve generated accordingly to handles and type of point. It used to create some basic round shapes (like paths and motion guides) and can be optionally convert to Mesh.

You can convert curve to mesh from menu `object -> Convert to -> Mesh form Curve[..]`,

Answer (score 0):

when add a circle, choose it from mesh, mot curve.
I don't know why either but that worked for me.